# Passing data between stacked views

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, uiview, navigationcontroller

In my app, I've several views.. and some of these views are pushed and popped using the navigation controller. In some view, I have a table view, in which each one of its cells is a view itself, so when the cell is selected, this code is executed :

```
DetailView *detailViewController = [[Detailview alloc] initWithNibName:@"Detailview" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
```

and in the detailview this code will be executed, when a specific button is clicked (e.g. back/cancel button):

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

What I want is passing data from the detailview to the view that precedes it(the view that initialize it). So far, I've implemented a class named "Globals.h", in which I put the data I want to pass, and uses "extern" on these data variables to ensure it'll be global to many classes, and it worked properly. But I don't feel that this is the appropriate way to do so. Is there any other good ways to do that ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One easy way to solve it is:

```
DetailView *detailViewController = [[Detailview alloc] initWithNibName:@"Detailview" bundle:nil];
detailViewController.controller = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
```

and then in the detail view:

```
self.controller.data = data;
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I hope you know how to create properties, otherwise drop me a comment.

Comment: Yes, this approach is the preferred one in most of the cases, as you keep the view controllers communication restricted to them without involving other entities (singletons, extern, ...). Of course must be replaced by a delegate-based approach in case your detail view controller needs to be re-used inside the app (or by different apps), as a library component. Anyway if it's not the case keep the suggestion given in the answer.

Comment: @viggio24, I agree, using delegates would be a more general approach, but for this simple case I thought this solution would suffice.

Comment: Why use two steps, though? Just have the parent controller set the child's data property directly That way, the child doesn't have to know anything about the parent, which makes the child that much more reusable and maintainable. It's also less code: detailController.data = self.data; and you're done.

Comment: Guys, I don't know what to say.. It worked perfectly, thank you so much especially @Erik B

Comment: @ObjProg Then you might want to accept my answer. And if you really like it you could upvote it too. :)

Comment: @Caleb It's a question about passing data between from child view to parent view. But your comment is for parent to child view..I think so.